# Match string numbers with Ruby regex

Tags: ruby, regex, puppet

I need help to match string(s) with ruby regular expression. (it's for puppet)

1. How can I match everything that has the numbers: 001 to 010, in the end.

**Example: master001, master002, master003**

2. And then I need to match everything that starts with: 011 to 999 in the end.

**Example: master011, master012 ..... master997, master998, master999**

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary no...... first group shouldn't contain something like 099 ... second group shouldnt contain 010.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: What math is required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I match everything that has the numbers: 001 to 010, in the end.

```
\w+0(?:0[1-9]|10)
```

> And then I need to match everything that starts with: 011 to 999 in the end.

```
\w+(?:0[1-9]|[1-9]\d)\d
```

See it live [here](https://regex101.com/r/sE6uE8/4) and [here](https://regex101.com/r/sE6uE8/3)
And as suggested by @Cary, you can run it with `str.scan`

Comment: I think my comment disappeared somehow. Thanks again mate! Works great. Have a good weekend.

Comment: `Thank you` comments or `+1` comments are moderated. From [helpCenter](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers): `Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional information – not for socializing.`. Anyway, have a good weekend to.

Comment: The inner non-capture groups serve no purpose. `(\w+0(?:0[1-9]|10))` is sufficient. Your first regex matches `'cat9001'`, which may or may not be wanted (the question is not clear on that). What is the reason for enclosing the match in a capture group, considering that you could just write `str.scan /\w+0(?:0[1-9]|10)/`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: The inner non-capture group avoid to match `cat0090`. You are right about `cat9001` as `\w+` is including digits. For you last question, I answered in general regex, so the way one can capture the result can vary (plus as I tested out with regex101, it shows me the result only when enclosing the match). Thank you for your review.

Comment: Your regex does match `'cat0090'`, because the first zero matches `'\w\'`. Think about it: how does `(?:abc)` differ from `abc`? It doesn't. (If `(?:a|b)` then it's needed, of course.) Can you suggest an example where having the capture group is helpful when it captures the entire match? There may be some but they don't come to mind.

Comment: Oups, nvm :D I tested out with the wrong regex somehow ... Anyway, I update my answer to show case your suggestions.

Comment: Regardless of what the Help Center says, I welcome (and author) comments that contain good puns or can otherwise bring a smile to the reader's face.

Comment: Your revised regex still matches `'cat0090'`: `'cat0090'[/\w+0(?:0[1-9]|10)/]
 => "cat009"`, but now because you have not required that it be followed by a non-digit or be at the end of the string.

Comment: That was intended, it can be easily adapt and I'm willing to let it as this to keep the regex simple and clear.

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt would be those 2 :

```
"master001".match(/010$|00[1-9]$/) #=> "001"  up to "009" "010"
"master099".match(/0[1-9]\d$|[1-9]\d\d$/) #=> "011" up to "999"
```

**Edit** : My 2nd attempt would be those :

```
"master001".match(/010$|00[1-9]$/) #=> "001"  up to "009" "010"
"master099".match(/0[1-9]\d$|[1-9]\d\d$/) #=> "010" up to "999"
```

The second regex  catches  010 but that's okay if you already cought it in the 1st one.

Anyway kudos to @Cyrbil.

Comment: You first regex includes 000 which is not what is wanted. The second one match 010 and fails at 100.

Answer (score 0):

"Everything" in "How can I match everything...". is quite vague. Can "everything" contain any characters, including spaces? What about "cat_1001", which is comprised entirely of word characters (`"cat_1001" =~ /\w+/ #=> 0`)? That string ends with the (string representation of the) number "1001" but whose last three characters are "001"? Should it be a match? Do you want to match the string "007" (three digits with nothing before)? I have assumed you want to match strings that:

- start at the beginning of the string or are preceded by a non-letter
- have one more letters (uppercase or lowercase)
- have three digits
- are at the end of the string or are followed by a non-digit

Suppose the string were:

```
str = "Ann010, Bee012, Bob001 and Hank999a are MI6; 007, Deb0001 and Paul000 aren't"
```

Applying the rules for matching that I've adopted, the first group (1-10) is comprised of Ann and Bob; the second group (11-999), Bee and Hank.

This can be accomplished with the following regex:

```
r = /
     [a-z]+ # match one or more letters
     \d{3}  # match three digits
     # (?!\d) # do not match another digit (negative lookahead)
    /ix     # case-indifferent and extended/free-spacing modes
```

to extract candidates:

```
arr = str.scan(r)
  #=> ["Ann010", "Bee012", "Bob001", "Hank999", "Deb000", "Paul000"]
```

which can then be extracted as desired:

```
arr.select { |s| (1..10).cover? s[-3..-1].to_i }
  #=> ["Ann010", "Bob001"] 
arr.select { |s| (11..999).cover? s[-3..-1].to_i }
  #=> ["Bee012", "Hank999"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Cyrbil's answer looks nice but it's a thinker and it overlooks stuff. You can play it safe with the somewhat uglier:

```
/\w+(?:#{('001'..'010').to_a.join('|')})\b/
```

and

```
/\w+(?:#{('011'..'999').to_a.join('|')})\b/
```